# How to do Positional Scroll in GroupedListView

Tags: flutter, chat, autoscroll, custom-scrolling, scrolltoindex

How to do Positional Scroll in GroupedListView. this is a one-to-one chat screen and I want to search for an element in the chat list and scroll to a specific index in the chat list I use grouped list view instead of the list view. means I want to scroll to index in grouped ListView.

```dart
controller.scrollToIndex(i, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
       preferPosition:AutoScrollPosition.middle );
```

in above, i is a index and i use scroll to index package of flutter. for scroll.